# Python programming help?

Tags: python

I have been trying to make a cash register like code, where the user types in their product name the price and the quantity. I have four products. After doing all the adding for these i need to get the 5% GST and then print out the total amount including the GST. This is what i could come with so far and i am new to python that's why i don't know a lot of error and other keywords. I get and ut in everything but when i multiply it says it can't multiply string and an integer. I tried changing the variable name and did all other stuff but it wouldn't give a total.

```
name1 =raw_input('What Item do you have: ')
price1 = float(input('What is the price of your item: '))
quantity1 = float(input('How many are you buying: '))
name2 = raw_input('What Item do you have: ')
price2 = float(input('What is the price of your item: '))
quantity2 = float(input('How many are you buying: '))
name3 = raw_input('What Item do you have: ')
price3 = float(input('What is the price of your item: '))
quantity3 = float(input('How many are you buying: '))
name4= raw_input('What Item do you have: ')
price4 = float(input('What is the price of your item: '))
quantity4 = float(input('How many are you buying: '))
sum_total= (price1 * quantity1), (price2 * quantity2), (price3 * quantity3), (price4 * quantity4),
print(' %.2f ' %  quantity1+quantity2+quantity3,' X ', name1+name2+name3,' @ %.2f ' %  
price1+ price2+price3,' = %.2f ' % total)
divv = sum_total / 100
percent = divv * 0.05
gst = sum_total + percent
print('The suggested gst is %.2f '% percent )
print('That will be a total of: %.2f '% gst)
```

Comment: plze just tell me hot to get the totals and how can i fix it
Thanks

Comment: If I just tell you how to fix it I would have to write you a completely new program, and you would learn nothing. There are two reasons why you would write such a program: Either as homework or for your own learning purposes. In both cases I do not want to give you a full solution.

Comment: @Yousuf you should really follow Björn Pollex's advice, and possibly read a good tutorial and other introductory materials. Two good possibilities are the python docs and the online book "Dive into Python".

Comment: No this is for my own purpose because i have a challenge with my friend and we are trying to make the same program and whoever findhes it first wins. I want to learn that's why i just want to know what am i doing worng and what approach can i take to fix it.

Comment: And i will definitely read the docs first now

Comment: Also, does your friend know you are asking the Internet for help? That's cheating ;)

Comment: "read the docs first" -> this is an excellent idea. This way you will not learn to solve a given simple task but you will be on your way to become a real programmer! The difference between blindly copy-and-pasting snippets found on the web and actually having an idea, solving a problem...

Comment: Bjorn probably his friend is asking, too ;-)

Comment: @Francesco: Good point about understanding and solving the problem instead of just blindly copying the solution! I have seen too much code that looked like someone randomly trying to solve the problem by copying some code into the program ;)

Comment: This question is asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26683509/loop-program-that-loops-inputs), most probably by your friend...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be simplified a lot.

Your code for **asking about products** could be simplified to this:

```
def ask_for_products(how_many):
    products = []
    for i in xrange(how_many):
        product = {
            'name': raw_input('What Item do you have: '),
            'price': float(input('What is the price of your item: ')),
            'quantity': float(input('How many are you buying: '))
        }
    products.append(product)
    return products
```

which will make your code more flexible and modular.

**Total sum** can be calculated like this (assuming `products` contains result of the above function):

```
total_sum = sum([i['price']*i['quantity'] for i in products])
```

**Suggested GST**, if I understand you correctly, is:

```
suggested_gst = .05 * total_sum
```

You can also print **list of products with prices and quantities**:

```
for p in products:
    print '%.2f X %.2f %s' % (p['quantity'], p['price'], p['name'])
```

Comment: Thank you 
I undrestand my code is long because i am new. See i dont know many things so i am not gunna use it thats y want to learn and just try to get the total in this and i will ask a question if i can't get the gst to work but thanks a lot really appreacite it

Comment: Sorry but when i put it in this is what i got:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yousuf/NetBeansProjects/pythonpretest/src/pythonpretest.py", line 18, in <module>
    total_sum = sum([i['price']*i['quantity'] for i in a])
NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Comment: @YousufSiddiqui: I have pasted the code that had `a` variable instead of `products`, forgot to change it. I have now corrected my answer so it is more readable and should work for you.

Comment: This is what i got when i used your simplified version:
  File "/home/yousuf/NetBeansProjects/pythonpretest/src/pythonpretest.py", line 14
    return products
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Comment: @YousufSiddiqui: Corrected :) My `return products` had incorrect indent (bug appeared when copying the code into StackOverflow).

Comment: Sorry but when i put in your simplified version it says "i" (third row) is unused variable

Comment: @YousufSiddiqui: This is not a bug, this should not throw any error - it is only for loop. Just ignore it.

Comment: But it doesn't run anything. In my run screen nothing comes up

Comment: @YousufSiddiqui: I gave you pieces of the code that you should use in your own manner. If you have problems with that, just place all the code in the file and after function definition (first piece of the code I gave you) add the following line: `products = ask_for_products(4)`. This will ask for 4 products and assign them to `products` variable. By the way: good way to learn Python is to use IDLE (command line Python interpreter). It will help you to see the results instantly.

Answer (score 1):

I see many strange things here. I would recommend the following approach:

1. Write your program so that it can handle a single product.
2. Then add a second product.
3. Now think about a loop.

If you have trouble with a specific step, ask a question here.

Comment: i am new to this so i dont know how to make a loop but why would the price and the quantity? I am supose to mutilpy the two and then the next one and so on and all of them together after i get the total

Answer (score 1):

What is sum_total? 
You are writing

```
sum_total = something, something else, something else again
```

(notice the ",")

Wouldn't it be better to write

```
sum_total = something + something else + something else again
```

? (notice the "+" sign)

Your first line was a tuple (search for it on the python docs!) and not a number.

Answer (score 0):

The `sum_total` is a [`tuple`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences). Shouldn't you add them together instead?

Comment: i am not sure can u please tell where and how can i do this. I searched it on google but i don't undrestand i am new to this.

Comment: @YousufSiddiqui Check Francesco's answer.